# Javascript script not scraping time-typed data(?)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function hoursWorked(){

   //This is a line to help debug
   alert("entered hoursWorked() function")

    var date = new Date();
    var hour = date.getHours(),
        min  = date.getMinutes();

    hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
    min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;

    var endtime = hour + ":" + min; 
    var starttime = hour + ":" + min;

document.getElementById("endtime").value = endtime;
document.getElementById("starttime").value = starttime;
/*The above block is, as I understand it, how you are supposed to work with military time in javascript.  
I think i may have referenced the id's wrong.*/

if (starttime > endtime) {
    var hoursworked = (endtime + 12:00) - (starttime - 12:00);
        if (hoursworked < 08:00) {
            alert("Shift entered as less than 8 hours, please double check before 
submitting");
}}  else {
        var hoursworked = (endtime - starttime);
            if (hoursworked < 08:00) {
                alert("Shift entered as less than 8 hours, please double check 
before submitting");
}}       
}

document.getElementById("endtime").addEventListener.on('change', hoursWorked());
</script>
```

The event listener also might be wrong.

```
<label class="yard/ylard" name="lya">Start Time:</label>
<br>
<input id="starttime" name="ly"type="time" size="20" step="1800" required>
<br>


<label>Finish Time:</label>
<br>
<input id="endtime" name="iy" type="time" size="20" step="1800" 
onchange="hoursWorked();" required>

</html>
```

So this code is supposed to take the time input from two fields and compare them against each other. If the end time is less than the start time, the end time has 12 hours added while the start time has 12 hours subtracted. This is to get around not pulling the date information as the date for both fields will remain the same.

Because it pulls in military time, I added those lines to prefix a "0" before any time less than 10:00. This is in our site for users to log their hours worked. If they worked less than 8 hours we would like to send an alert to the user asking them to double check the information they inputted.

I'm not very experienced with Javascript syntax, so what I have here was mostly pieced together with snippets on the internet combined with my knowledge of other programming languages. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I haven't read your whole question, but '<% Response.Write("entered hoursWorked() function")%>' is not going to show whether the `hoursWorked()` method is being called or not. It is going to render output out to the page, and would be viewed by viewing source on your html page. If you want to know whether or not the javascript method is being called, you should `console.log('message');` or `alert('message')`;

Comment: Are you sure? I had someone who is well versed in .asp put that line in themselves. I will try your method locally regardless.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you addressed your issue in a more concise way.  Here you are asking why a javascript function is not working and then you are mixing asap.  By evaluate are you saying you just want to be able to look at it?

Comment: The .asp is very negligible, I only commented on it in case it was confusing someone. I'm looking for absolutely zero .asp help here.

Comment: So far it looks like its not even scraping the id fields properly, However since i'm not a daily javascript coder, I cant tell if it IS scraping and that something else is throwing a kink in the works so i thought it would be best to include all the code involved in this task.

Comment: @Jonathan I edited in the alert method, however it has not returned anything.

Comment: So that means that your event listener is not firing as you have it. That's the first main step to tackle before looking into any algorithm / time processing issues

Comment: Always check the error console! F12 in most browsers you have an error on this line `var hoursworked = (endtime + 12:00) - (starttime - 12:00)`  12:00 is not a valid javascript value. In javascript  you basically can have strings, numbers or objects. In javascript terms `endtime + 12:00` is meaningless. Basically you need to convert your hours worked into a purely numeric value, most likely minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following changes first, I've removed the inline event handler from the html and the javascript event listener is now `document.getElementById("endtime").addEventListener('change', hoursWorked);` . I have removed `on` as that is from the jQuery library and removed `()` after hours worked. The important point there is that `hoursWorked` assigns the method to the event listener where `hoursWorked()` runs the method immediately.

Now onto the fundamental issues. `8:00` is not a valid numeric value for javascript, you can't perform mathematical functions or comparisons with it. We need to work with something javascript understands. I've chosen minutes for the below.

```js
/*Set up values outside the event listern*/
var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours(),
  min = date.getMinutes();

hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;

var endtime = hour + ":" + min;
var starttime = hour + ":" + min;

document.getElementById("endtime").value = endtime;
document.getElementById("starttime").value = starttime;

/*Convert military time to minutes*/
function timeToMinutes(militaryTime) {
  var timeArray = militaryTime.split(":");
  return timeArray[0] * 60 + parseInt(timeArray[1], 10);
}

function hoursWorked() {

  //This is a line to help debug
  alert("entered hoursWorked() function")

  //Get raw values
  var startTime = document.getElementById("starttime").value;
  var endTime = document.getElementById("endtime").value;

  //convert to minutes
  startTime = timeToMinutes(startTime);
  endTime = timeToMinutes(endTime)

  //Adjust for overnight shift
  if (startTime > endTime) {
    endTime += 24 * 60;
  }

  var minutesWorked = endTime - startTime;
  console.log(minutesWorked / 60);

  if (minutesWorked < (8 * 60)) {
    alert("Shift entered as less than 8 hours, please double check before submitting");
  }
}

document.getElementById("endtime").addEventListener('change', hoursWorked);
```

```html
</script>
The event listener also might be wrong.

<label class="yard/ylard" name="lya">Start Time:</label>
<br>
<input id="starttime" name="ly" type="time" size="20" step="1800" required>
<br>


<label>Finish Time:</label>
<br>
<input id="endtime" name="iy" type="time" size="20" step="1800"  required>
```

Comment: this looks perfect, i'm still working on making it run properly but i think this is very helpful. Thanks for explaining where i was going wrong too, the time was confusing me bad. I've never had to work with it before.

Comment: can i remove everything above the second comment line? It doesn't seem to serve a further purpose.

Comment: The top section of the code sets the initial start and end time values, if you don't need that, you can get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your event listener is not firing. You should make a few changes. Here is a slightly stripped down example. You should reference the handler by name, not name and parentheses, as you are not 'calling' the handler directly, you are passing through a 'reference' to it.

Also, I don't think the `change` event will fire unless you set an initial value for the time picker. I have done that below.

You might want to be careful with the `time` input control; I don't believe it works in IE. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

```js
function hoursWorked(){

    alert("entered hoursWorked() function");

    var date = new Date();
    var hour = date.getHours(),
        min  = date.getMinutes();

    hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
    min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;

    var endtime = hour + ":" + min; 
    var starttime = hour + ":" + min;

  document.getElementById("endtime").value = endtime;
  document.getElementById("starttime").value = starttime;
}

document.getElementById("endtime").value = '00:00';
document.getElementById("endtime").addEventListener('change', hoursWorked);
```

```html
<label class="yard/ylard" name="lya">Start Time:</label>
<br>
<input id="starttime" name="ly"type="time" size="20" step="1800" required>
<br>


<label>Finish Time:</label>
<br>
<input id="endtime" name="iy" type="time" size="20" step="1800" required>
```

Comment: IE not handling time is okay, this is an internal site that only gets run on chrome

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/*Convert military time to minutes*/
function timeToMinutes(militaryTime) {
  var timeArray = militaryTime.split(":");
  return timeArray[0] * 60 + parseInt(timeArray[1], 10);
}

function hoursWorked() {


  //Get raw values
  var startTime = document.getElementById("starttime").value;
  var endTime = document.getElementById("endtime").value;

  //convert to minutes
  startTime = timeToMinutes(startTime);
  endTime = timeToMinutes(endTime)

  //Adjust for overnight shift
  if (startTime > endTime) {
    endTime += 24 * 60;
  }

  var minutesWorked = endTime - startTime;


  if (minutesWorked < (8 * 60)) {
    alert("Shift entered as less than 8 hours, please double check 
before submitting");
  }
}
document.getElementById("endtime").addEventListener('change', 
hoursWorked);
</script>


<label class="yard/ylard" name="lya">Start Time:</label>
<br>
<input id="starttime" name="ly" type="time" size="20" step="1800" 
required value="06:00">
<br>


<label>Finish Time:</label>
<br>
<input id="endtime" name="iy" type="time" size="20" step="1800"  
required value="17:00" onchange="hoursWorked()">
```

> This is the final code that runs, thanks for the help guys!!!